# How to DRY these two "while condition do"?

Tags: c#, while-loop, dry

I have a function like this (`parent` and `formToBeShown` are WinForms form instances):

```
if (parent == null)
    while (!formToBeShown.IsDisposed)
        Do();
else
    while (!parent.IsDisposed && !formToBeShown.IsDisposed)
        Do();
```

I find these extremely inelegant. I would love to have the `Do` function called only once. Or even better if I can incorporate all the condition in one while loop. Don't know if I am having a brain fart, but I can not think of a way to achieve this. Some thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think using below code, you can use while loop only once.

```
while (!formToBeShown.IsDisposed && (parent == null || !parent.IsDisposed))
        Do();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well let's consider this logically.

The first loops conditions can be written out as the following:

```
(parent == null && !formToBeShow.IsDisposed)
```

The second loop's conditions are:

```
(!parent.IsDisposed && !formToBeShown.IsDisposed)
```

You basically have 3 boolean variables:

Let A: parent == null
Let B: !formToBeShow.IsDisposed
Let C: !parent.IsDisposed

Now you can simplify to

```
// Loop1 || Loop2  call Do() When:
(A && B) || (C && B)
```

Using the rules of boolean logic, this becomes:
    B && (A || C)

```
while(!formToBeShow.IsDisposed && (parent == null || !parent.IsDispoed))
    Do();
```

You need to make sure that the parent == null check comes first to that it may shortcut and avoid trying to dereference null.

There's a problem with this though, you're doing additional work by checking (parent == null) on each loop. So technically, if you wanted to bring this outside of the loop and write more than one, you could perhaps have justification. Although, for something so simple, I'd probably prefer the single loop.

Comment: Thanks good explanation. Let me mark jags answer since he came up first

Comment: both answers are right, but sometimes it's not the race to see who gets it first, but who took the time to answer AND explain they why. Future readers will get a more beneficial answer from @Alan... just sayin.